# Vectorial calculus statement proving

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

See this statement:
$$
|u×v|^2=|u|^2\cdot|v|^2-(u\cdot v)^2
$$

I need to prove this is right.

I only found that:
$$
u×v=|u|\cdot|v|\cdot\sin\theta
$$
and
$$
u.v=|u|\cdot|v|\cdot\cos\theta
$$

Does this helps?

Answer (score 2):

$$|u\times v|^2=|u|^2|v|^2\sin^2\theta$$
$$=|u|^2|v|^2(1-\cos^2\theta)$$
$$=|u|^2|v|^2-(u\cdot v)^2$$

Your equation isn't right. Take $(1,0,0)\times(0,1,0)=(0,0,1)$. The dot product is $0$, and the lengths of the starting vectors are equal. The formula above gives $1$ (the correct length), while yours would give $0$. Where did you find that formula?

Comment: sorry my bad, now it's correct

Answer (score 1):

According to what you wrote:
$$|u\times v|^2=|u|^2|v|^2\sin^2\theta$$
$$|u|^2-|v|^2-(u\cdot v)^2=|u|^2-|v|^2-|u|^2|v|^2\cos^2\theta$$
So if the left sides are equal also the right ones are:
$$|u|^2|v|^2\sin^2\theta=|u|^2-|v|^2-|u|^2||v|^2\cos^2\theta\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow|u|^2|v|^2=|u|^2-|v|^2$$which of course is far from being true in general. Check your equalities.